# How can i make the code print backwards recursively?

Tags: java, string, recursion

Here's my code.
I am trying to make the String entered print out backwards, but every time I run it the code doesn't print out anything when it's called to print in reverse.

```
package Pali;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by alexa on 11/4/2016.
 */
public class Palindromes {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String msg;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        msg = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\nThe string backwards: ");
        printBackwards(msg);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static String printBackwards(String s)
    {
        if (s.length() == 0)
            return s;

        return printBackwards(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you could start by printing (and not ignoring) what `printBackwards` returns ...

Answer (score 3):

`printBackwards` actually just returns a `String`, but does nothing else. To print that returned `String` you would have pass it to the `println` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String msg;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    msg = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\nThe string backwards: ");
    String reversed = printBackwards(msg);
    System.out.println(reversed);
}
```

Alternatively, you can let `printBackwards` print the `String` and leave the main method as it was:

```
public static String printBackwards(String s)
{
    if (s.length() == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
        return s;
    }
    return printBackwards(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you forgot to print letters

```
public static void printBackwards(String s)
{
    if (s.length() == 0) return ;
    printBackwards(s.substring(1));
    System.out.print(s.charAt(0));
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/OOlera#comments)

Comment: This prints the original string, not-reversed.

Comment: @xoxox  Did you see demo?

Comment: No I am not sure (in fact I mixed up lines). The return type still has to be `String`

Comment: No need to return anything if we check for string `length == 0`

Comment: Right. Completely confused. And not very intuitive :/

Comment: I mean, method name indicates `print` action so no need to return a `string`. If anything useful need to be return from it would be `int` number of characters printed.

Answer (score 0):

Iteratively:

```
static String printBackwards(String s) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
     sb.append(s.charAt(i));
   return sb.toString();
 }
```

Recursively:

```
static String printBackwards(String s) {
   if(s.length() == 0)
     return "";
   return s.charAt(s.length() - 1) + reverseMe(s.substring(0,s.length()-1));
 }
```

Comment: If you are already using `StringBuilder` anyway, you can as well just use its `reverse()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code calls printBackwards, but immediately discards the output.

Try changing line 6 of main() to `System.out.print(printBackwards(msg));`

Given that, I would also think about changing the method name to something like `reverseString(String)`.